# How to integrate google analytics in android application and how to see Dashboard of GA?

Tags: android

I had integrated GA in My app but still not able to get any data on GA dashboard.can anyone explain how to do it. dont add any link i had already checked all the sites regarding this.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
   tracker=GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
   tracker.startNewSession("id",this);
   tracker.trackPageView("page");
   boolean isTracker = tracker.dispatch();
   Log.v(TAG, "isTracker   "+isTracker);
 }

 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() 
 {
    super.onDestroy();
    tracker.stopSession();
    Log.v("newslistView","onDestory()");
  }
```

Thank You.

Comment: can you please share your code with us ?